# Why $C(S,F)$ is only a subspace for a number of finite elements in $ S$

Tags: linear-algebra

The original question is:

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and F a field. Let $ C(S,F) $ denote the set of all functions $f \in F(S,F) $ such that $f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$.

Prove that $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $F(S,F).$

Now it is fairly easy to verify that $ C(S,F)$ is a subspace, but I do not understand why $f(s) = 0$ can only hold for all but a finite number of elements of $S$. It seems that if we allow infinitely many elements, the zero vector still exists, and it is still closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without the restriction we obtain $F(S,F)$ which is indeed a vector space, $C(S,F)$ being a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example will hopefully make it clearer:

$C(S,F)$, more commonly denoted $F^{(S)}$, as opposed to $\mathcal F(S,F)$, also denoted $F^S$, are the underlying vectors spaces of the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F$, $F[X]$, and of the ring of formal power series, $F[\mkern-2mu[X]\mkern-2mu]$ respectively.